# git output is blank, except when captured as in: echo "$(git branch)"

Tags: git, shell, homebrew, zsh, gnu

I'm having a strange issue, and I really can't tell whether it's caused by something related to my Git install or my shell, or something else entirely. If I'm in a Git repository with plenty of branches and commits, and I try to list branches:

```sh
$ git branch
$ git branch -a
$ git branch --list
```

There is no output at all. However, if I run the output of these commands through `echo` the results are as one might expect:

```sh
$ echo "`git branch`"
  local-branch-1
  local-branch-2
* master
$ echo "$(git branch -a)"
  local-branch-1
  local-branch-2
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

My configuration is macOS 10.14.6 with Git 2.29.2 installed via Homebrew. I'm using ZSH 5.8 (also Homebrew) with either Prezto or PowerLevel10k configurations. While these tools alias plenty of shortcuts to Git commands, nothing is aliased *from* `git *` that could be interfering:

```sh
$ type git
git is /usr/local/bin/git
git is /usr/bin/git
```

I've also tried a virgin Bash 5.0.18 shell, and the results are the same.

ZSH tab completion shows the branches correctly, so if I, for example:

```sh
$ git checkout <tab>
local-branch-1   master
local-branch-2   origin/HEAD
HEAD             origin/master
```

I'm getting similar behavior from some other Git commands, for example `git config --local --list`. But all of the "action" commands (`push`, `pull`, `add`, `commit`, etc.) seem to work as intended, including the proper output. (But so do some "info-only" commands, like `git version`.)

This feels to me like some kind of shell configuration error, but it's only affecting Git as far as I can tell, and it happens in both my fancy ZSH installation and vanilla Bash, so maybe some weird interaction between the two? I've searched high and low for anyone else with a similar problem, but everything I've found boils down to branches not being listed on a fresh repository with no commits, which definitely isn't the case here.

I'm kind of out of ideas at this point, so I'm hoping someone has a suggestion for further investigation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224548/discussion-on-question-by-chris-git-output-is-blank-except-when-captured-as-in).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## If this only happens when output is to the TTY, it's probably a pager issue.

When running in a regular terminal, unless you capture or redirect git's output with `$(git ...)` or `git ... | otherprogram`, `isatty(1)` is true, so git automatically invokes a pager to let users read content too long to fit on one screen.

## If it's a pager issue, there are several options to debug.

1. See if the problem goes away without a pager.

   - Does `git --no-pager branch` still have issues?
2. Check which pager is in use.

   - `declare -p GIT_PAGER` will show a pager configured *only* for `git` via the environment.
   - `git config core.pager` will show a pager configured *only* for `git` via its config files.
   - `declare -p PAGER` will show a pager configured to be used by your OS in general.
3. Check how that pager is configured, and try clearing or simplifying that configuration.

   - If your pager is `LESS`, `declare -p LESS` will show options configured for it via the environment, and `unset LESS` will temporarily clear those options.
   - If your pager is `MORE`, `declare -p MORE` will show options configured for it via the environment, and `unset MORE` will temporarily clear those options.
   - For another pager, consider reading its manual.

---

## Regarding this specific instance:

The OP had `LESS='-F -g -i -M -R -S -z-4'` `export`ed in their environment. The `-F` argument to `less` instructs it to exit if there's less than one page of content to be displayed.

On the OP's (MacOS) system, the stock version of `less`, when called with `-F`, exited *before* emitting the original content to stdout; this could be repaired either by removing that flag, or by installing a newer version of `less`.

Comment: OK but this doesn't actually show posterity the answer to the question, which seems to be that the OP had marred LESS by saying `export LESS='-F -g -i -M -R -S -z-4'`, yes?

Comment: @matt, the goal of an answer is to be applicable to everyone, not just the OP. I doubt anyone else would have that exact same string, so I'm not confident that including the string in the answer itself would add any utility; the goal is to write an answer helpful to _everyone_ who has a misconfigured pager.

Comment: This was the issue. My `PAGER` environment variable was set to use `less` which was the macOS system binary in `/usr/bin`. I also had a `LESS` environment variable that included `-F` as an option to exit automatically if the input was less than a full page. I believe there may have been a bug in that version of `less` (v487) that caused the exit to happen before displaying any input. Removing `-F` shows the output, but keeps the pager open on short input, which is undesirable. However, installing Homebrew's `less` (v551) fixed this for me, while allowing me to keep the `-F` option. Thank you!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't agree. Your answer as it stands is just a (valuable) set of diagnostic instructions; it nowhere states the actual cause of the actual issue the OP has. I think this is a really interesting Q&A and I don't want its benefit to be lost to posterity. The OP merely _commenting_ on your answer with the actual cause of the issue is insufficient, as comments are volatile. I'm suggesting that you should put an addendum into your _answer_ revealing what the OP has now revealed about the specific cause of the problem, as _that_ is the info that needs preserving.

Comment: @matt I think the key pointer here was "pager." I would've eventually figured this out with that single clue, but before you folks led me in that direction, I was totally trying to dissect my Git and ZSH configurations for the cause, which had been fruitless. Thanks guys.

Comment: And to be clear, the root cause wasn't actually the pager configuration, but rather the way that v487 of `less` was exiting before showing any of the input when passed the `-F` option. The exact same configuration works as expected on v551. Since this is the system version for macOS Mojave, there are potentially a lot of people who would be similarly affected, since Apple doesn't tend to upgrade these things between minor OS versions.

Comment: @matt, as-edited, the answer explicitly recommends `unset LESS`. That suggestion, on its own, solves the OP's problem, and also variants of it that don't rely on `-F` to get the same behavior (and happen to be on platforms with a version of `less` where `-F` has undesired behavior). This way we cover both the OP's immediate problem, _and_ also other as-yet-undiscovered routes to the same class of failure (of which there's an infinite/indefinite number).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I still feel we'd all be better off if, say, the OP added a self-answer, to preserve the actual specific solution to the actual issue. Or you could copy the OP's "This was the issue" comment into your answer as a kind of addendum. My goal is to preserve the facts about what actually happened.

Comment: @matt, addendum added.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, sorry to badger you but I think this really improves the situation.